# Find and copy values between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble copying some data between 2 dataframes. I have the main_df:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [123, 456, 789, 357, 159], "date": [None, "2022-10-10", "2022-09-15", None, "2022-09-15"], "stuff": [3, 6, 2, 9, 3]})


id             date  stuff 
123             NaN      3
456      2022-10-10      6
789      2022-09-15      2
357             NaN      9
159      2022-09-15      3
```

and second_df:

```
second_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [321, 456, 789, 789, 351], "stuff": [3, 6, 2, 4]})


id   stuff 
321      3
456      6
789      2
351      4
```

I want to search if an id in ***second_df*** is in ***main_df*** and copy the date that appear in ***main_df*** to ***second_df***. This would be the result:

```
id   stuff         date
321      3          NaN
456      6   2022-10-10
789      2   2022-09-15
351      4          NaN
```

I know that with `second_df["id"].isin(main_id["id"])` I can get a dataframe/column/Series with boolean results indicating if the id exists, but I don't know how to copy the date value.

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map to bring over the date value

```
df2['date']=df2['id'].map(df.set_index('id')['date'])
df2
```

```
id  stuff   date
0   321     3   NaN
1   456     6   2022-10-10
2   789     2   2022-09-15
3   351     4   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks I believed it work, I still have to test it well, then I let you know. Now I'm filtering the data with dropna in base of a column. The real data has more columns and more NaN /NaT.

Comment: any idea how could I do this if I wanted to copy id, and stuff, from main_df to second_df? I was trying with: `df2['id2', 'stuff2']=df2['id'].map(df.set_index('id')['id', 'stuff'])` but it's not working. Thanks

Comment: Map returns only a single value. if you need to multiple columns then pd.merge is an option

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on that

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Im reading about `pd.merge`, but I wanted to ask about the case if **df** had repeted ids, for example: `"id": [123, 456, 789, 357, 456]`. The code you send returns this error: `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` because the index is repeated. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: how you like to handle this duplicate situation? can these duplicate rows be removed? In case of merge with duplicate in DF, you end up with multiple rows in your second DF

Comment: Mmmm right now I would say that I don't mind the duplicate rows, but that's because I know I can use `pd.duplicate` or `pd.drop_duplicate` to delete them. I'm not 100 % sure what case I need more. Thanks